# Volume of an n-simplex

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, volume, simplex

It's rather tedious to show using Fubini's Theorem and induction on $n$ that the volume of the region $x_1+x_2+...+x_n \leq 1$ with $x_1,...,x_n$ nonnegative is $\frac{1}{n!}$.  Is there an easier way to see this?