# What is the size of $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_1+\cdots+x_n<a\text{, and }x_i>0\}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, volume, simplex

Is there an easy way to compute the size (Lebesgue measure) of the set
$$S_n(a):=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_1+\cdots+x_n<a\text{, and }x_i>0\}.$$
Using integration I computed that
$$m(S_n(a))=\frac{a^n}{n!}.$$
But the computation is tedious, and I was wondering if there are more concise/direct ways of proving it.

**Computation:**
$$
\begin{align}
m(S_n(a)) &= \int_0^a\int_0^{a-x_1}\cdots\int_0^{a-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1}}dx_n\cdots dx_1 \\
&= \int_0^a\int_0^{a-x_1}\cdots\int_0^{a-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-2}}(a-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1})dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_1 \\
&= \int_0^a\int_0^{a-x_1}\cdots\int_0^{a-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-3}}\frac{-1}{2}(a-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1})^2\big|_0^{a-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-2}}dx_{n-2}\cdots dx_1\\
&=\int_0^a\int_0^{a-x_1}\cdots\int_0^{a-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-3}}\frac{1}{2}(a-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-2})^2dx_{n-2}\cdots dx_1\\
\end{align}
$$
and so on...

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304245/what-are-your-favorite-proofs-using-mathematical-induction/304267#304267) a proof using induction and a fundamental property of integration with respect to product measures.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of $0 < y_1 < y_2 < \dots < y_n < a$ is $\frac{a^n}{n!}$ as there are $n!$ permutations.  If you let $x_1 = y_1$ and $x_i = y_i - y_{i-1}$ for $1 < i \le n$ then this has the same volume (the Jacobian is 1).

See [Volume of an n-simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315298/volume-of-an-n-simplex) for more detail.